# Blackberry.location API not working correctly

Tags: api, blackberry, blackberry-widgets

I am experimenting with making Blackberry widgets but having a little trouble.

My first trial involves displaying a button which, when clicked, calls a JavaScript function that should alert the phones latitude and longitude.

The function looks:

```
function whereAmI() {
var latitude = blackberry.location.latitude;
var longitude = blackberry.location.longitude;
alert("Lat: "+latitude+", Long: "+longitude);
}
```

But it only ever alerts "Lat: 0, Long: 0".  I've checked and my GPS seems to be working ok.

I'm running OS 5.* on a Curve 8900.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I wasn't signing my files properly - now that I have, everything works fine.

For kaban:

```
      // called when location object changes
  function locationCB()
  {
     alert("Latitude "  + blackberry.location.latitude);
     alert("Longitude " + blackberry.location.longitude);
     return true;
 }
 // test to see if the blackberry location API is supported
 if( window.blackberry && blackberry.location.GPSSupported)
 {
       document.write("GPS Supported");

       // Set our call back function
       blackberry.location.onLocationUpdate("locationCB()");

       // set to Autonomous mode
       blackberry.location.setAidMode(2);

       //refresh the location
       blackberry.location.refreshLocation();
 }
 else
 {
   document.write("This Device doesn't support the Blackberry Location API");
 }
```

Comment: sadly i wish you had provided more on what 'signing my files properly' meant, so this could have helped others...

Comment: Good point.  When you register with RIM to become a developer of apps or widgets, you get a code signing key which marks your apps with a unique code so that in the event of malicious use, the developer can be traced.  There are a number of ways of signing your files, and I wasn't doing it properly.  I can provide specifics if anyone else is interested.

Comment: If you have any links it would be helpful for others in the future! 

Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your widget have permission to use GPS?  Go to Options->Applications, select your app, then "Edit Permissions".   Make sure "Location Data" (in Connections) is set to Allow.

Comment: Hi, Marc.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I had a look and the application definitely has access to the location data, and nearly everything else, yet it still returns 0.