# BlackBerry Location Support

Tags: html, blackberry, geolocation

I've seen the posts about requiring a signing code in order to access location functionality in BlackBerry (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876050/blackberry-location-api-not-working-correctly) but is this required even for a website? I too am getting 0 for both latitude and longitude... but signing codes appear to be for native apps, not websites. I would really appreciate any tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location API does not need code signing in order to access, but location data is considered priviledged and the application will need user permission to access it. There is also a system to allow the user to authorize websites to access location data but I`m not very familiar with it.

I talked to my boss who actually uses JS access to the blackberry location. He just followed the [documentation here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/CS_Retrieving_a_GPS_loc_by_using_a_web_page_924231_11.jsp). Though he did say that before I upgraded him to a 9000 running OS 5.0 it was a bit hit and miss. The only other advice he had was it is slow and you have to wait for it.

Comment: Thanks Richard. This is going through the browser, and blackberry.location.GPSSupported is returning true... however, blackberry.location.latitude and blackberry.location.longitude both return 0.

Comment: "Have to wait for it" <- good to know. I'm doing a check and immediate redirect based on the value. Perhaps I need to put a timer in place. Thanks!